# How do I move the Delete and Add icon to the right of the input fields using Grid?

Tags: css, reactjs, grid

Here's what I am able to create

[My UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usnSq.png)

And here is what I want to achieve:
[The aspiration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQxpg.png)

Here's my code:

```
<Grid container spacing={3}>        
   <Grid item md={4} xs={15}></Grid>
   <Grid item md={4} xs={15}></Grid>
   <Grid item md={4} xs={15}></Grid>
   <Grid item md={3} xs={15}><TrashIcon> <AddIcon></Grid>
</Grid>
```

Additional (Edited)
How do I align the grid fields in the bottom to the ones on top rows?
[new confusion but have a limit on questions per hour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AirxA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [auto-layout feature](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/#auto-layout) of the `Grid`:

> The Auto-layout makes the items equitably share the available space.
> That also means you can set the width of one item and the others will
> automatically resize around it.

```
<Grid container spacing={3}>
  <Grid item md xs={12}>
    <input style={{ width: "100%" }} />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item md xs={12}>
    <input style={{ width: "100%" }} />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item md xs={12}>
    <input style={{ width: "100%" }} />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item md="auto" xs={12}>
    <TrashIcon /> <AddIcon />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-yonath-g27w3o?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: Thank you, I have another question related to this, could you please have a look at that too? I have edited the question to include it.

Comment: You are welcome. Just set `md={3}` for all items or use the CSS grid for full control. Don't hesitate to open a new question. But please provide code for the whole form.